# Blazor Layout Not Rendering

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am new to Blazor. The `AdminLayout.razor` file I have doesn't seem to be rendering any components.

I have a `Routed.razor` component:

```
<Router AppAssembly="typeof(Startup).Assembly">
    <Found>
        <RouteView RouteData="@context" DefaultLayout="typeof(AdminLayout)" />
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <h4 class="bg-danger text-white text-center p-2">
            No Matching Route Found
        </h4>
    </NotFound>
</Router>
```

I have an `AdminLayout.razor` component:

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<div class="bg-info text-white p-2">
    <span class="navbar-brand ml-2">Administration</span>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row p-2">
        <div class="col-3">
            <NavLink class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-block"
                     href="/admin/models"
                     ActiveClass="btn-primary text-white"
                     Match="NavLinkMatch.Prefix">
                Models
            </NavLink>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            @Body
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My `Index.cshtml` file:

```
@page "/admin"
@{ Layout = null; }

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Admin</title>
    <link href="/lib/twitter-bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <base href="/" />
</head>
<body>
    <component type="typeof(Routed)" render-mode="Server" />
    <script src="/_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My `Models.razor` component:

```
@page "/admin/models"
@page "/admin"

<h4>This is the models component</h4>
```

The `Index.cshtml` file appears to load because the tab title correctly displays "Admin" but there is no other rendered components. The razor component `Models.razor` does not render nor does the content of `AdminLayout.razor`.

My routing in `Startup.cs` is

```
endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/admin/{*catchall}", "/Admin/Index");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was missing information in my `_ViewImports.cshtml` file. Specifically, I needed:

`@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers`

The Blazor components now render correctly.